Ubuntu 24.04 crashed - unable to automount SSD after force restart
Background
I have a dual-boot installed on two SSD drives. One is Windows 11 and the other is Ubuntu Desktop 24.04.
Yesterday, my Ubuntu system crashed, and I can't enter tty shell. So I have to force restart.
Luckily, my system and all HDD/SSD drives are good.
Unfortunately, one SSD is unable to automount to /media when I click it like before.
Although I can mount it manually, I still want to known what happened after the crash. I hope this SSD can be automounted like other HDD/SSD drives when I click it from bottom menu.
Can anyone give me some advice?

Clues
journalctl -xe
11月 13 10:20:31 usename-pc tracker-miner-fs-3[23503]: (tracker-extract-3:23503): GLib-GIO-WARNING **: 10:20:31.507: Error creating IO channel for /proc/self/mountinfo: 无效的参数 (g-io-er>
11月 13 10:20:43 usename-pc tracker-miner-fs-3[23636]: (tracker-extract-3:23636): GLib-GIO-WARNING **: 10:20:43.119: Error creating IO channel for /proc/self/mountinfo: 无效的参数 (g-io-er>
11月 13 10:20:45 usename-pc microsoft-edge.desktop[4901]: Fontconfig error: Cannot load default config file: No such file: (null)
11月 13 10:20:45 usename-pc microsoft-edge.desktop[4901]: [4947:4953:1113/102045.400351:ERROR:ssl_client_socket_impl.cc(892)] handshake failed; returned -1, SSL error code 1, net_error -100
11月 13 10:20:55 usename-pc tracker-miner-fs-3[23686]: (tracker-extract-3:23686): GLib-GIO-WARNING **: 10:20:55.780: Error creating IO channel for /proc/self/mountinfo: 无效的参数 (g-io-er>

tail /var/log/syslog
2024-11-13T10:24:30.677338+08:00 usename-pc tracker-miner-fs-3[24194]: (tracker-extract-3:24194): GLib-GIO-WARNING **: 10:24:30.676: Error creating IO channel for /proc/self/mountinfo: 无效的参数 (g-io-error-quark, 13)
2024-11-13T10:24:41.383113+08:00 usename-pc tracker-miner-fs-3[24278]: (tracker-extract-3:24278): GLib-GIO-WARNING **: 10:24:41.382: Error creating IO channel for /proc/self/mountinfo: 无效的参数 (g-io-error-quark, 13)
2024-11-13T10:24:41.425386+08:00 usename-pc microsoft-edge.desktop[4901]: [4894:4894:1113/102441.425166:ERROR:interface_endpoint_client.cc(725)] Message 0 rejected by interface blink.mojom.WidgetHost
2024-11-13T10:24:52.025510+08:00 usename-pc tracker-miner-fs-3[24369]: (tracker-extract-3:24369): GLib-GIO-WARNING **: 10:24:52.025: Error creating IO channel for /proc/self/mountinfo: 无效的参数 (g-io-error-quark, 13)
2024-11-13T10:25:01.018299+08:00 usename-pc CRON[24401]: (root) CMD (command -v debian-sa1 > /dev/null && debian-sa1 1 1)
2024-11-13T10:25:05.211864+08:00 usename-pc tracker-miner-fs-3[24407]: (tracker-extract-3:24407): GLib-GIO-WARNING **: 10:25:05.211: Error creating IO channel for /proc/self/mountinfo: 无效的参数 (g-io-error-quark, 13)
2024-11-13T10:25:07.690463+08:00 usename-pc systemd[1]: Starting fwupd-refresh.service - Refresh fwupd metadata and update motd...
2024-11-13T10:25:07.722400+08:00 usename-pc systemd[1]: fwupd-refresh.service: Deactivated successfully.
2024-11-13T10:25:07.722494+08:00 usename-pc systemd[1]: Finished fwupd-refresh.service - Refresh fwupd metadata and update motd.
2024-11-13T10:25:15.936874+08:00 usename-pc tracker-miner-fs-3[24441]: (tracker-extract-3:24441): GLib-GIO-WARNING **: 10:25:15.936: Error creating IO channel for /proc/self/mountinfo: 无效的参数 (g-io-error-quark, 13)
2024-11-13T10:25:26.476227+08:00 usename-pc tracker-miner-fs-3[24464]: (tracker-extract-3:24464): GLib-GIO-WARNING **: 10:25:26.476: Error creating IO channel for /proc/self/mountinfo: 无效的参数 (g-io-error-quark, 13)
2024-11-13T10:25:37.372215+08:00 usename-pc tracker-miner-fs-3[24484]: (tracker-extract-3:24484): GLib-GIO-WARNING **: 10:25:37.371: Error creating IO channel for /proc/self/mountinfo: 无效的参数 (g-io-error-quark, 13)
2024-11-13T10:25:47.479607+08:00 usename-pc tracker-miner-fs-3[24494]: (tracker-extract-3:24494): GLib-GIO-WARNING **: 10:25:47.479: Error creating IO channel for /proc/self/mountinfo: 无效的参数 (g-io-error-quark, 13)

'smartctl' --info --health --capabilities '/dev/sdd'
martctl 7.4 2023-08-01 r5530 [x86_64-linux-6.8.0-48-generic] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-23, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Model Family:     Phison Driven SSDs
Device Model:     KINGSTON SA400S37480G
Serial Number:    xxx
LU WWN Device Id: 5 0026b7 38301c9bc
Firmware Version: SAN20102
User Capacity:    480,103,981,056 bytes [480 GB]
Sector Size:      512 bytes logical/physical
Rotation Rate:    Solid State Device
TRIM Command:     Available
Device is:        In smartctl database 7.3/5528
ATA Version is:   ACS-3 T13/2161-D revision 4
SATA Version is:  SATA 3.2, 6.0 Gb/s (current: 6.0 Gb/s)
Local Time is:    Wed Nov 13 10:37:21 2024 CST
SMART support is: Available - device has SMART capability.
SMART support is: Enabled

=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: PASSED

General SMART Values:
Offline data collection status:  (0x00) Offline data collection activity
                    was never started.
                    Auto Offline Data Collection: Disabled.
Self-test execution status:      (   0) The previous self-test routine completed
                    without error or no self-test has ever 
                    been run.
Total time to complete Offline 
data collection:        (  120) seconds.
Offline data collection
capabilities:            (0x11) SMART execute Offline immediate.
                    No Auto Offline data collection support.
                    Suspend Offline collection upon new
                    command.
                    No Offline surface scan supported.
                    Self-test supported.
                    No Conveyance Self-test supported.
                    No Selective Self-test supported.
SMART capabilities:            (0x0002) Does not save SMART data before
                    entering power-saving mode.
                    Supports SMART auto save timer.
Error logging capability:        (0x01) Error logging supported.
                    General Purpose Logging supported.
Short self-test routine 
recommended polling time:    (   2) minutes.
Extended self-test routine
recommended polling time:    (  10) minutes.

sudo fsck /dev/sdd
usename@usename-pc:~$ sudo fsck /dev/sdd
fsck，来自 util-linux 2.39.3
e2fsck 1.47.0 (5-Feb-2023)
ext2fs_open2：超级块中的幻数有错
fsck.ext2：超级块无效，正在尝试备份块...
fsck.ext2: 超级块中的幻数有错 尝试打开 /dev/sdd 时

超级块无法被读取，或它未能正确地描述一个有效的 ext2/ext3/ext4 文件系统。
如果设备有效并确实为 ext2/ext3/ext4 文件系统（而非 swap 或 ufs 等格式），
这说明超级块已经损坏，您可能需要指定备选超级块来运行 e2fsck：
    e2fsck -b 8193 <设备>
 或
    e2fsck -b 32768 <设备>

在 /dev/sdd 中发现一个 dos 分区表

sudo blkid
usename@usename-pc:~$ sudo blkid
/dev/sdb2: UUID="081470ff--????---????--ba96-3dcd12b7a0f8" BLOCK_SIZE="4096" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="fa267313-4dfa-????-????-2c8fa2fe9f12"
/dev/loop1: BLOCK_SIZE="131072" TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop19: BLOCK_SIZE="131072" TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/sdd1: LABEL="code_space" BLOCK_SIZE="512" UUID="A27A6????AE5" TYPE="ntfs" PARTUUID="c832????-01"
/dev/loop17: BLOCK_SIZE="131072" TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop25: BLOCK_SIZE="131072" TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/sdb1: UUID="9F3B--????-" BLOCK_SIZE="512" TYPE="vfat" PARTUUID="dfc51496-????--????--a1cb-723dc731dc8a"
/dev/loop15: BLOCK_SIZE="131072" TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop6: BLOCK_SIZE="131072" TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop23: BLOCK_SIZE="131072" TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop13: BLOCK_SIZE="131072" TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop4: BLOCK_SIZE="131072" TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop21: BLOCK_SIZE="131072" TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop11: BLOCK_SIZE="131072" TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop2: BLOCK_SIZE="131072" TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop0: BLOCK_SIZE="131072" TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop18: BLOCK_SIZE="131072" TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop9: BLOCK_SIZE="131072" TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop26: BLOCK_SIZE="131072" TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/sdc2: PARTLABEL="Microsoft reserved partition" PARTUUID="534d64be--????---????--81cc-b6f5d7c12fc7"
/dev/sdc3: BLOCK_SIZE="512" UUID="3952EC-????-7F3" TYPE="ntfs" PARTLABEL="Basic data partition" PARTUUID="9664f6a5--????---????---????--eeabf27b57bc"
/dev/sdc1: UUID="3C4B--????-" BLOCK_SIZE="512" TYPE="vfat" PARTLABEL="EFI system partition" PARTUUID="5c54a3e0-8-????--????---????--215601e8ef2b"
/dev/loop16: BLOCK_SIZE="131072" TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop7: BLOCK_SIZE="131072" TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop24: BLOCK_SIZE="131072" TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/sda4: BLOCK_SIZE="512" UUID="88042-????-74B8E" TYPE="ntfs" PARTUUID="06cd5035--????---????--b611-df96c85bd394"
/dev/sda2: PARTLABEL="Microsoft reserved partition" PARTUUID="10936ee2-b687--????---????--c0a0b58c79f3"
/dev/sda3: BLOCK_SIZE="512" UUID="74F4FC-????-C86A0" TYPE="ntfs" PARTLABEL="Basic data partition" PARTUUID="24ce83f0--????---????--a60c-7f8a928884d6"
/dev/sda1: UUID="7ADB--????-" BLOCK_SIZE="512" TYPE="vfat" PARTLABEL="EFI system partition" PARTUUID="830a6dbe--????---????--b32d-013e3ef39a08"
/dev/loop14: BLOCK_SIZE="131072" TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop5: BLOCK_SIZE="131072" TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop22: BLOCK_SIZE="131072" TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop12: BLOCK_SIZE="131072" TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop3: BLOCK_SIZE="131072" TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop20: BLOCK_SIZE="131072" TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop10: BLOCK_SIZE="131072" TYPE="squashfs"

Result
I still haven't figured out why I can't automatically mount, but I'm going to use fstab to do this

finnally, fixed in windows11, SSD right click context menu. Maybe it used chkdsk command , not sure.
